# How to enable SSH Verbose mode from configuration file

Tags: ssh

I'm trying to enable SSH client verbose mode ( equivalent to 'ssh -v ...' ) from configuration file (ssh_config) but I can not figure out the correct Key-Value pair.

I tried already the *LogLevel* key but seem only to affect logging level in unix log subsystem

Any ideas...??

Thxs !!

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: I don't think it's possible, at least I never found out how. I ended up making an alias (assuming you are on a unix-like system) like, alias vssh="ssh -vvv"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is `LogLevel` option, where `-v` to `-vvv` corresponds to `DEBUG` to `DEBUG3` arguments.

Comment: There is also a `LogLevel VERBOSE` level, which is less verbose than `DEBUG` but more verbose than the default `INFO` level.

Comment: Is DEBUG3 the most verbose level?

Comment: @majorgear yes.

Comment: @Jakuje Thanks! I set up a way to pass the loglevel into my docker image I'm working on to troubleshoot ssh connection failures. It's proving to be very helpful , so take up my upvote.